# Basic Shell scripting with control structures. Counting the number of directories and files and whether they are readable writeable and executable

Tags: shell, scripting

write a shell script that calculates the following information for the contents of a given directory. The directory is to be specified as a single command line argument to your script. You do not need to account for any contents of nested subdirectories -- just the direct contents of the specified directory.

The total number of directories that are in the given directory (note that these are subdirectories).
The total number of files in the given directory.
The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are readable.
The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are writable.
The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are executable.

I tried :

if [ -d $file ] 
then
  counter=`expr $counter + 1`
  echo "Number of directories    :" $counter
fi

Comment: As this is a homework question, you need to help yourself first -- what have you tried so far? What don't you understand? Where is your script falling over? Quoting the question verbatim won't generally get you anywhere.

Comment: i know if i do, if [ - d $file ] it will see if the current directory is a directory i dont understand how to look inside a directory and count its files and directories

Comment: @Chris J, glad to see a more reasonable response than the *'BAHHH ITS HOMEWORK DONT HELP HIM!'* that I often see on SO.

Comment: No need to be rude. Im in an intro class and im having problems. I added the code i tired.

Comment: sorry tom i didnt realize that was u

Comment: You will need to perform a loop of some kind, either using `for` and testing each file from a glob, or using `find` and counting resultant lines. If you want more specific answers I recommend posting your entire script.

Comment: @instanceOfTom -- Everyone was a newbie once. I don't try to hold a holier-than-thou attitude unless (a) there's something in the question that merits it or (b) I'm in a bad mood :-) (a) could have come into play here as the question was given verbatim, but @Andrew K was a new user, so needed some lee-way for ettiquette.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the script for you, but one way to obtain the answer is to use `ls -l` an association with `grep -c`, using grep to parse out the appropriate filesystem flags (the `drwxrwxrwx` column) that `ls -l` will give you. The key is knowing how to parse this column with `grep`.

It may not be the most efficient (as we're doing `ls` multiple times, but it will give you what you're looking for.